# Hide/Archive documents in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, archive

How can I archive documents on SharePoint online, i.e. hiding them down the list somewhere without losing them altogether?

Answer (score 2):

there are many ways, to achieve this, here are two *simple* approaches:

1. You can create a new view in the library (and make it the default view or just change the existing default view), that "archived" documents are not visible any more in this default view. To "archive" them, you could add a boolean column to the list with the name "archived" and set it by default to false. In the view, you can now filter to show only documents where archived is "not true".
2. Move to other library. Create a new library with the name "archive". Documents you want to archive can be moved to a different library in the same site via the browser UI. You could also just create a directory "archive" and move the documents to archive there. (Disadvantage on moving is, that the link is changing)

Answer (score 2):

To archive the document in SharePoint online, you could enable the retention policy for content type, document library and so on.

To enable the retention policy in the document library, go to library settings->Information management policy settings->select the content type->Enable Retention.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

How to set up retention and deletion policies for files and folders in SharePoint.

https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/

Retention Policy in SharePoint 2013.

https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/retention-policy-in-sharepoint-2013/

And you also could create a separate Records Center site or a Document Center site to manage the documents.

Use a Document Center site.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-Document-Center-site-06096070-d83f-45b8-b02d-ec7a4cf85cac

Implement Records Management.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Implement-Records-Management-0bfe419e-eb1d-421a-becd-5be9fed1e479

Comment: i am testing the retention policy on document content type,its not working. can you elaborate on the steps to take please?

Answer (score 1):

A vital need for any enterprise in SharePoint implementation is to “archive” sites that are no longer used.

Before defining the requirements for “archive”, you should know the answers for question below

- When should a site to be archived?
- How is the archiving process triggered?
- What happens to a site when it is archived?

The option explained below will help you in defining a strategy for archiving

**Option #1: Change the Site Settings**

Just modify the permissions of the site to "read only" or even lock it down for further access so that it will be no longer read by intranet users.

**Option #2: Move the Site**

Move your site to a separate “archived” area within your site structure using Microsoft Content and Structure tool which requires Publishing feature to be enabled.

**Option #3: Use a Third Party Tool for Archiving**

There as plenty of SharePoint archiving tools like [Vyapin Dockit Archiver](https://www.vyapin.com/products/dockit-archiver) which provides so many out of the box archiving features.

**Option #4: Site Based Retention Policy**

SharePoint 2013 supports a site based retention policy that can archive a site based on policy rules. To know more about it- https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/

**Option #5: Implement a Custom Workflow**

Using the Site Policy concept, you can elect to run a workflow to manage site closure which  adds additional business logic to the transition of state from open to closed